# Map CMD on PC keyboard (switch ALT and WIN and set "new WIN" as Meta)

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

Is there an easy way to add CMD key to PC keyboard on Ubuntu?

Currently I have Slovenian (si) layout:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/859847/si.png

and would like to switch "Alt L" with "Super L" and also set "Super L" as Meta, so I could use Mac keymapped shortcuts on PHP Storm etc. (like on MacBook Air)

`setxkcmap -print` currently shows:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwertz)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+si+us:2+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

I already tried to editing `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and change LWIN and ALT + include "altwin(meta_alt)" to include "altwin(meta_win)", than clearing cache with `rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*`, but didn't work..

I also tried setting through `setxkbmap -option "altwin:swap_lalt_lwin, altwin:meta_win"` but couldn't get it work also..

Any ideas for a permanent solution? It's a bit of an overkill to have to learn all the shortcuts for both Mac and Ubuntu in PHP Storm.. :)

Thanks in advance!